# Assigning value to allocated char array fails

Tags: c++

I simply allocate some memory for a character and wanna do then some pointer arithmetic.
In this case I wanna write '\x0a' to byte 32 as follows:

```
#define HDR_SIZE 32   

int size = 52;

unsigned char *readXPacket = (unsigned char *) malloc (size * sizeof (unsigned char));
*readXPacket + HDR_SIZE = '\x0a';
```

When I try doing that I get the following error message: non-value in assignment. Anyone an idea what is wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Change your assignment to:

```
*(readXPacket + HDR_SIZE) = '\x0a';
```

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with the obvious:

```
readXPacket[HDR_SIZE] = '\x0a';
```

which is both shorter and clearer. and as you are using C++, why not say:

```
unsigned char * readXPacket = new unsigned char[size];
```

Or better still:

```
std::vector <unsigned char> readXPacket( size );
```

and have C++ manage the memory for you.

Answer (score 5):

Try...

```
*( readXPacket + HDR_SIZE ) = '\x0a';
```